# Difference between 'wait' and '@' statement

Tags: verilog

The following set of codes do the same thing.Is there any difference between them ?If not , why is `wait (clk)` not generally used?

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin

end


always wait(clk)
begin 

end
```

Comment: Note that the second `always` block will hang the simulator when `clk` goes to 1 if there are no other delays inside the block. It will go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@(posedge clk)` is edge sensitive , hence it is used to model synchronous circuits.While, `wait(clk)` is level sensitive.Since most circuits are designed to be synchronous `@(posedge clk)` is predominantly used

```
wait (expression)
```

The "expression" is evaluated, if false, then execution is suspended until the expression becomes true. If the expression is true when the statement is reached, then the wait has no effect, and execution proceeds to the controlled statement.

```
@(posedge clk) - is an edge event.
posedge:0,x,z->1    negedge:1,x,z->0
```

Edge events are useful for modelling clocked logic elements, like flip-flops. They are also useful for synchronizing activity in a model based on a common clock. Example, in the following always block,it enters the `always` block on the negative edge of clock.

```
always @(negedge clock)
    x = f(y);
```